# Windows service and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a solution with three projects: a web application, the data access layer to create the code first database and a windows service which I (would like to) use for syncing some data in the database. 
I have also referenced the data layer in both of the other projects. I am using the same connection string in the web application config and the service config. Everything works fine for the web application, but when I access the data context all the tables are empty (Enumeration yielded no results). I get no errors.
So my question would be that am I missing something obvious?

```
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=Purple Moose; Integrated Security=True; User Id=purplemoose; Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Where is your database located? Did you check why it's empty?

Comment: It is a local database. It is not empty actually. I use the same credentials to access it from SSMS and everything is there. Also the web application accesses the data just fine, but when I debug the windows service all the tables are empty.

Comment: Do you use the same user for connecting? How does the connection string look like, does it have user/password or does it use the current windows user to authenticate?

Comment: Same user for both. I updated the question with the connection string I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string uses the current windows user for login to your database. You specified **both**, integrated security (aka windows user) *and* username/password.

In that case:

> Windows authentication takes precedence over SQL Server logins. If you specify both Integrated Security=true as well as a user name and password, the user name and password will be ignored and Windows authentication will be used.

So you will always lo into your database with the current windows user and that is probably `Local System` or something similar for your service. Either way, as you want username/password authentication, **remove** `Integrated Security=true` or set it to false.

Comment: That is a really good point, thank you. I removed it and left everything else as it was. Did the same for the web app. Everything still works for the web app, but I now get an error 'Login failed for user' for the windows service. Which is still progress. But why doesn't it say the same for the web app?

Comment: @sandra I just noticed you are using LocalDB. LocalDB is *local to the user* of the operating system. It would lead too far to go through all the intricacies of a local db. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb).